# Sql Update field value with each other

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an sql table as follows:

```
id      position
----------------
1       1
2       2
```

Now I want to interchange the position of id which means that I need to o/p as follows:

```
id      position
----------------
1       2
2       1
```

So I tried this:

```
$update1 = "UPDATE table SET pos=(pos-1) WHERE pos = 2;
$conn->query($update1);
```

But the problem is now that the table has two positions with the same value so how can I update both with each other as the shown result above ?

Comment: will there always be 2 rows ?

Comment: yes.there is two rows.

Comment: Are you sure for your field name? 
`"` is missing in your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE example_table
   SET position = CASE id
                 WHEN 1 THEN 2
                 WHEN 2 THEN 1
                  END
 WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

Comment: what is diffn between "BETWEEN 1 AND 2" & "IN (1, 2)"

Comment: The `BETWEEN` operator selects a range of data between two values. And `IN` will return the only rows with matching attributes given inside of `()`

Answer (score 1):

If all you really have is two rows, then an update with a `CASE` expression should be able to handle this:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET position = CASE WHEN position = 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END
WHERE id IN (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

option -1

```
UPDATE table SET pos = (CASE pos WHEN 1 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END) WHERE pos = 2;
```

option-2

If the values are always 0 or 1, you could use the Bitwise Exclusive OR operator.

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1 SET col2 = (col2 ^ 1);
```

Comment: you give the right solution but it isn't work if i have more than 2 id

Comment: then you can extend CASE condition because without CASE i think it is not possible for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try orderBy command on your code. SQL code is

> SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY position desc;

in that case your whole position column will be reversed. 
I don't know the php but ı am sure you can modify that command for your usage.